# HTML is loading before Vue Instance is getting loaded

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using Axios to fetch JSON from external API and creating a bill template in HTML. My other request parts are working fine. But this part Vue is throwing error that "property is undefined".
I tried wrap the html code between script tag and also tried to `windows.onload()` function to trigger my script before page loads, but the error threw in the other direction in this way.

Here is my Vue code

```
    <script>             
    $(document).on('click', '#btn_print', function(){ 
    var app3 = new Vue({
        el: '#app3',
        data: {
          printOrders: []
        },            
    mounted: function() {
        this. printExtraBill()
    },            
    methods: {          
        printExtraBill() {
            axios.get(`https://staging/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/137? 
        consumer_key=ck_123&consumer_secret=cs_456`)               
        .then(response => {
          this.printOrders = response.data;
          console.log(response);
          })
         .catch(error => {
         console.log(error);              
        });
    }
   }
 });
}
</script>
```

Here is my HTML Part

```
    <div class ="container mt-5" id="app3">
      <div id="printToday" style="border:3px solid black">
          <h2 align="center">Name</h2>
          <h4 align="center">Address and Mobile</h4>
               
     <p v-for="orders, index in printOrders" id="getName">Id: {{orders.number}} <br> 
        {{orders.date_created}} <br>
        {{orders.billing.first_name + " " + orders.billing.last_name }}
     </p>
   <div>
     <h3 class="thick" v-for="(orders, index) in printOrders" id="total">
          Total : {{orders.total}} </br> Method : {{orders.payment_method_title}}</h3>
```

Error

```
Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined"
vue.js:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined
    at eval (eval at createFunction (vue.js:11649), <anonymous>:3:568)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.js:2658)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at createFunction (vue.js:11649), <anonymous>:3:359)
    at Vue._render (vue.js:3551)
    at Vue.updateComponent (vue.js:4067)
    at Watcher.get (vue.js:4478)
    at Watcher.run (vue.js:4553)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.js:4311)
    at Array.<anonymous> (vue.js:1989)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.js:1915)
```

Any help please.....

[image: JSON Data First part]

[image: JSON Data current Error part]

Comment: could you please include full error stack trace as well?

Comment: Hi @Dipen Shah, i just have attached the error with the question

Comment: Looks like `billing` property is null on orders, can you verify it?

Comment: No, i verified it, actually i get the JSON data filled up with each element i defined....

Comment: I doubt it, could you please include `printOrders` JSON object as well in your question?

Comment: Its a long JSON with many nested arrays. I am pretty sure that I am getting the array filled...

Comment: You can include truncated version, just one object will be sufficient.

Comment: @Dipen Shah, please have look on the pictures i have attached with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that your `billing` property is always defined, but if you say so following should be able to take care of your issue:

```
<p v-for="orders, index in printOrders" id="getName">Id: {{orders.number}} <br> 
    {{orders.date_created}}
    <br />
    <span v-if="orders.billing">
        {{orders.billing.first_name + " " + orders.billing.last_name }}
    <span>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi @Dipen Shah, Thanks for the answer. I get the JSON data particular for that order, i can view that in the console. But when i used the v-if as you said, then i get one more undefined property for nested array. I think I am doing something wrong when i use the Vue instance. Just for a question, we can use multiple Vue instances right. This is my third Vue instance handling this particular Get request.

Comment: @Tom I am not sure what do you mean by multiple instances of Vue, multiple vue components are definitely supported.

Comment: May be if you can share codesandbox/stackblitz I can help further.

Comment: I have done the in the same way to fill up other table in the same page through Axios request. For this part only, I am getting this issue...

Comment: I see but without looking at data I am not sure what I can help with as problem seems to be with undefined property value, may be you can debug you JS and see where problem is.

Comment: Let me try to paste the data in the question

Comment: What is other undefined property it is complaining about?

Comment: ` {{orders.tax_lines[0].tax_total}} ` . Here error gets throwing like "'0' of undefined"

Comment: @Tom using index directly will definitely cause an issue when array is empty, you need similar `v-if` which will check if `tax_lines` is not undefined and has certain length: `<span v-if="orders.tax_line && orders.tax_line.length > 0"></span>`

Comment: @ Dipen Shah, as you said, i check each element and finally the errors are vanished. But i get nothing as results and weird styling of my template. How it can be happen as I am getting the data perfectly, any idea???

Comment: That shouldn't happen, unless your data is null/undefined itself.

Comment: it could be not relevent to this question. But I hope that you might have a simple answer to answer my new question. If you can please have a look on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370588/displaying-dynamic-data-in-html-page-from-vue-js"....Thanks

Comment: @ Dipen Shah, Yeah, if you can go through it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `mounted` lifecycle to `created` as follows:

```
async created(){
    await this.printExtraBill()
}
```

The `mounted` hook isn't called when loading the page so the data props won't be set : https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted

> This hook is not called during server-side rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still I am getting the error of "Undefined property"...

Comment: @Tom Based on your stack trace, it looks like some orders might not be getting the `billing` prop or getting it as `null`.
Try adding the validation to check for null before printing it.

`{{orders.billing ? orders.billing.first_name + " " + orders.billing.last_name: '-' }}`

Comment: I am just getting only one order for the testing purpose, for that order i am getting the first name and other elements as well...