# Displaying dynamic data in HTML page from Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, api, vue.js

I am trying to display bill structure in Html page from getting the data in Vue and in Axios. So i have a table where orders will be listed. In each row of the table I have a button named "Print". So what I am trying to archive is when the Print button clicked, I need to display the particular order details in a div.
My method is, first I am getting, in which row the Print button is clicked then in that row i ll get the OrderID of the order, then I am trying to get the Order details in the JSON array(Already fetched).

I could not realize How i can make connection between the Script and the HTML to say to get that details of that order only using `v-for` only. What I tried is below.

Script to get the ID

```
printBill(){
       // Get the row selected and get the Order Id first
    var rowSelected;
    var col;
    // Get the table
    var getTable = document.getElementById('table1');
    
    var tbody = getTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
       rows[i].onclick = function() {
        rowSelect = this.rowIndex;
        console.log(this.rowIndex);
        
       for (var i=rowSelect;i<rowSelect+1;i++) {
       col= getTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
       alert(col);       
       }
       }
    }      
  }
```

HTML to display order details in a structure

```
<div id="printToday" id="app1" style="border:3px solid black">
          <h2 align="center">Name</h2>
          <h4 align="center">Address</h4>
                   
          <p v-for="(orders, col) in todayOrders" id="p1">
       Id: {{orders.number}} <br> {{orders.date_created}} <br> <br/> 
        {{orders.billing.first_name + " " + orders.billing.last_name }}
           </p>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate your row code inside a div, and associate a `click` action to it. Your JS code to find which one is clicked is useless. In your HTML:

```js
<div v-for="(order, col) in todayOrders">
  <p @click="rowDidClick(order)">
     Id: {{order.number}} <br> {{order.date_created}} <br> <br/> 
        {{order.billing.first_name + " " + orders.billing.last_name }}
  </p>
</div>
```

In your JS code:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    rowDidClick(orderObjectThatHasBeenClicked) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Check the [Vue.js guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html), it is by far one of the best documentation written.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thing is, in my table each row has a button, same button. So when first row button clicked i am trying to display the order details for the ID which first row has. I don't know that I am mistakenly understanding your answer.

Comment: @Tom as onekiloparsec suggested you need to render html table using vue and than you can configure callback on button that you have in each row to open row specific order details.